# Not able to Install HAWQ DB successfully in Centos 7.x version

Tags: hawq

I am installing HAWQ DB on Linux Centos 7.X version, it is giving following issue in make install step as mentioned in link https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/HAWQ/Build+and+Install#tab-yum

```
make[2]: *** [install] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/ApacheSoft/incubator-hawq/depends/thirdparty/googletest/build'
make[1]: *** [install] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/ApacheSoft/incubator-hawq/depends/thirdparty/googletest'
make: *** [install] Error 2
```

I have taken all the steps in sequence given in link, Can any body help me here.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that it is caused because of cmake:

```
make -C depends/thirdparty/googletest install
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/build/hawq/depends/thirdparty/googletest'
cd ../../..//depends/thirdparty/googletest/ && mkdir -p build && cd build && 
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local/hawq ..
/bin/sh: cmake: command not found
make[1]: *** [pre-config] Error 127
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/build/hawq/depends/thirdparty/googletest'
make: *** [install] Error 2
```

You may try creating a symbolic link as follows:

```
ln -s /usr/bin/cmake3 /usr/bin/cmake
```